# xmlschema element is not an element of the schema

Tags: python, xml, xpath, xsd

Decoding a part of a XML document using [xmlschema](https://xmlschema.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#decoding-a-part-using-xpath) and XPath, selecting all `item` elements that have the attribute name and value `doc_id=2` fails.

### This is my xml file `simple.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<na:main
        xmlns:na="ames"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="ames ./simple.xsd">
    <na:item doc_id="1" ref_id="k1">content_k1</na:item>
    <na:item doc_id="2" ref_id="k2">content_k2</na:item>
</na:main>
```

### And this is my xml schema file `simple.xsd`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:na="ames"
           targetNamespace="ames"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

   <xs:complexType name="itemtype">
      <xs:simpleContent>
          <xs:extension base="xs:string">
               <xs:attribute name="doc_id" type="xs:int" />
               <xs:attribute name="ref_id" type="xs:string" />
         </xs:extension>
        </xs:simpleContent>
   </xs:complexType>

   <xs:complexType name="maintype">
         <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="item" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="na:itemtype" />
         </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>

   <xs:element name="main" type="na:maintype" />

</xs:schema>
```

### This is my python code:

```python
>>> import xmlschema
>>> xs = xmlschema.XMLSchema('simple.xsd')
>>> xs.is_valid('simple.xml')
True
>>> xs.to_dict('simple.xml', ".//na:item[@doc_id=1]")
{'@doc_id': 1, '@ref_id': 'k1', '$': 'content_k1'}
>>> xs.to_dict('simple.xml', ".//na:item[@doc_id=2]")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XMLSchemaValidationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-57-8ff81c2eaf9c> in <module>
----> 1 xmlschema.XMLSchema('simple.xsd').to_dict('simple.xml', ".//na:item[@doc_id=2]")

/rao/uhome/rmol3/bin/anaconda3_rmol3_lglxs408_2/envs/MW41_Quicklook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xmlschema/validators/schema.py in decode(self, source, path, schema_path, validation, *args, **kwargs)
   1553         """
   1554         data, errors = [], []
-> 1555         for result in self.iter_decode(source, path, schema_path, validation, *args, **kwargs):
   1556             if not isinstance(result, XMLSchemaValidationError):
   1557                 data.append(result)

/rao/uhome/rmol3/bin/anaconda3_rmol3_lglxs408_2/envs/MW41_Quicklook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xmlschema/validators/schema.py in iter_decode(self, source, path, schema_path, validation, process_namespaces, namespaces, use_defaults, decimal_type, datetime_types, converter, filler, fill_missing, max_depth, depth_filler, lazy_decode, **kwargs)
   1540                 else:
   1541                     reason = "{!r} is not an element of the schema".format(elem)
-> 1542                     yield schema.validation_error(validation, reason, elem, source, namespaces)
   1543                     return
   1544

/rao/uhome/rmol3/bin/anaconda3_rmol3_lglxs408_2/envs/MW41_Quicklook/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xmlschema/validators/xsdbase.py in validation_error(self, validation, error, obj, source, namespaces, **_kwargs)
    904
    905         if validation == 'strict' and error.elem is not None:
--> 906             raise error
    907         return error
    908

XMLSchemaValidationError: failed validating <Element '{ames}item' at 0x7eff7913db90> with XMLSchema10(basename='simple.xsd', namespace='ames'):

Reason: <Element '{ames}item' at 0x7eff7913db90> is not an element of the schema

Instance:

  <na:item xmlns:na="ames" doc_id="2" ref_id="k2">content_k2</na:item>

Path: /na:main/na:item[2]
```

What is wrong with the XPath statement `".//na:item[@doc_id=2]"`?

Comment: `"/na:main/na:item[@doc_id=1]"` gives `{'@doc_id': 1, '@ref_id': 'k1', '$': 'content_k1'}`. `"/na:main/na:item[@doc_id='1']"` throws the shown `XMLSchemaValidationError` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The schema processor doesn't find the matching schema element for decoding data because the provided path is not suitable to be used on schema elements. You have to provide an explicit *schema_path* that point to the right XSD element:

```
>>> xs.to_dict("simple.xml", "/na:main/na:item[@doc_id=2]", schema_path="/na:main/na:item")
{'@doc_id': 2, '@ref_id': 'k2', '$': 'content_k2'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following XPath:

```
   /na:main/na:item[@doc_id='2']
```

[image: Working XPath expression]

Comment: The suggested XPath leads to the same XMLSchemaValidationError. At least `/na:main/na:item` is working and gives `[{'@doc_id': 1, '@ref_id': 'k1', '$': 'content_k1'}, {'@doc_id': 2, '@ref_id': 'k2', '$': 'content_k2'}]`.

Comment: I just added a screen shot of the working XPath expression to the answer.

Comment: This is evidend, what you´re showing, fine thanks Yitzhak. Might be an issue concerning the xmlschema package.

Comment: Not sure why we are still discussing XPath syntax. The _reported_ problem is a schema validation error. The XPath will never even be executed until that is fixed.

Comment: So no question about the XPath syntax itself. Rather, it is something with the xmlschema package used.

Answer (score 0):

The XPath is not relevant - it can only be executed if the XML document can be parsed. But you are getting a Schema Validation error from the XML parser. It is claiming that the root tag in your document is not declared in your XSD. *However*, I have tested your XSD and XML in https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html and it validates OK.

Please check that the XML/XSD combination that you posted is the one that you tested with - that might explain the rather puzzling situation.

Comment: Kimbert, the shown XML/XSD are exactly these I tested with. `xmlschema.XMLSchema('simple.xsd').is_valid('simple.xml')` yields True (valid). Might be an issue concerning the used xmlschema package.

Answer (score 0):

More examples that work:

```python
>>> import xmlschema
>>> xs = xmlschema.XMLSchema('simple.xsd')

>>> xs.to_dict('simple.xml', ".//na:item[@doc_id='2']", schema_path='.//na:item')
{'@doc_id': 2, '@ref_id': 'k2', '$': 'content_k2'}

>>> xs.to_dict('simple.xml', ".//na:item[@doc_id=2]", schema_path='.//na:item')
{'@doc_id': 2, '@ref_id': 'k2', '$': 'content_k2'}
```